# Rank of  Matrix (derivative of a smooth map)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $D\subset \mathbb R^2$, open set. We have a smooth map $f: D\times (0,1)\to \mathbb R^3$.
There is a smooth map $u$ from some open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ to $ D$ such that  $$u(f(x,y,t)) = (x,y)$$  Show that $u_*$ derivative of $u$ is of rank $2$.  $t$ is parameter for $(0,1)$ direction and $(x,y)\in D$.

Any suggestion comment please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chain rule shows $u_* f_* = \operatorname {id}_* = \operatorname {id}$ which means that $u_*$ is surjective, i.e. has full rank